# intel mkl fatal error when running kaldi gst live demo

Tags: python, intel-mkl, kaldi

[the output error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crk7y.png)i tried running `GST_PLUGIN_PATH=../../src/gst-plugin ./run-live.py` and get `intel mkl fatal error Intel MKL FATAL ERROR: cannot load libmkl_vml_avx2.so or libmkl_vml_def.so.`

i tried `export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.so`
but it did not fix it

i then tried `sudo pip3 install mkl`
after that i installed some other things `sudo pip3 install numpy scipy scikit-learn numexpr`

and the error is still present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you try export LD_PRELOAD=mklroot/lib/intel64/**libmkl_rt.so**

Comment: i tried what you suggested but i still get the same errors but there was only one slight change when i tried to run my python code again  `ERROR: ld.so: object 'mklroot/lib/intel64/libmkl_rt.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded (cannot open shared object file): ignored.`

Comment: mklroot - the path where mkl is installed on your system. you need to change this path accordingly your systems. by the default, it looks like as follow: 
/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/linux/mkl......

Answer (score 1):

I tried this export and it seemed to remove the  errors

`export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_def.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_avx2.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.so:/opt/intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_thread.so:/opt/intel/lib/intel64_lin/libiomp5.so`

the python script I'm using didn't work ass intended I'm not sure if the problem is with my solution or with the script it self but i thought i might help someone else if they get the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when running my code inside Google Colab and could solve it with:

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libmkl_rt.so
```